# Running remote script on remote interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, remote-server

I have a python script on a remote server. I would like to run it on the remote server itself. However, PyCharm is not installed on the remote server and I need PyCharm to debug the code.

I have PyCharm on my local computer and I would like to run the script (which is on remote server) on the remote server using PyCharm on my local machine. I am aware of Deployment tools and remote server host in PyCharm. I do not know how to make them work together.

Having the script on my local computer is not really an option for me as there are huge data files involved with the code and I have very limited storage on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's absolutely necessary to use Pycharm only for debugging on your remote server but if not, you can use pdb module for debugging too: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html